# Node.js vhost on WAMP?

Tags: node.js, apache, wamp, vhosts

I have a box running `**W**AMP (x64) + ssl + mongodb + memcache + node.js`
I couldn't find the answer anywhere, is there a way to setup `vhosts` in `Node.jS`?

I run a server app `(socket.io) 8080/443`. I'm looking for something not too destructive of my current setup/app. Is there a way to bind to `apache (2.4.7) vhosts`?